# golang timestamp conversion give different result for timezone synonyms

Tags: go, timezone

I know what [Moscow Time set to UTC+03:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Time)
So, timezone `Europe/Moscow` and `Etc/GMT+3` have to be the same

But its not

```
msk, _ := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Moscow")
gmt3, _ := time.LoadLocation("Etc/GMT+3")
fmt.Println("MSK", now.In(msk).Format(isoFmt))
fmt.Println("GMT+3", now.In(gmt3).Format(isoFmt))
```

[Check](https://play.golang.org/p/vxb_NUesBXr) yourself. What am I doing wrong?

play gives a very strange result for `isoFmt=time.RFC3339`

```
MSK 2009-11-11T02:00:00+03:00
GMT+3 2009-11-10T20:00:00-03:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two time zones are not actually synonyms. According to the [list of timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), `Europe/Moscow` has UTC offset of `+03:00`, while `Etc/GMT+3` has UTC offset of `−03:00`. [`Etc/GMT+3`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9203:00) is actually located somewhere in South America and some other locations.

So there is nothing wrong with Go (in this specific case), but the source of your confusion is very clear.